# Configuring Nginx to proxy two virtual private servers

Tags: nginx, webserver, virtualhost, reverse-proxy

I am setting up a Nginx front end server to server up two node apps running on separate ports (e.g. 8080 and 8081). I was following the [Nginx docs for configuring multiple virtual private servers](http://nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/web-server/), however Nginx throws error when I place the http {} syntax.

```
Restarting nginx nginx
...fail!
```

Here's the code:

```
http {

# Configuration specific to HTTP and affecting all virtual servers

server {
    # configuration of virtual server 1

    location /one {
        # configuration for processing URIs with '/one'
    }

    location /two {
        # configuration for processing URIs with '/two'
    }
}

server {
    # configuration of virtual server 2
}
}
```

When the http {} is removed nginx does not produce any errors.

```
Restarting nginx nginx
...done
```

I am currently running nginx version: nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu). **Can someone explain why this occurs?**

Comment: What file did you edit?  Usually there is one default `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` that has `http` directive and includes all other files.

Comment: I added my server blocks to /etc/nginx/ folder. It is there I placed the example.com.conf file and add the error with http.